# Update all /some / no columns depending on other column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I was wondering if it's possible to do the following in SQL (I'm using SQL Server 2008+, so vendor-specific stuff might be useful as well for the time being):

I have the following table:

```
contact (contactid, fullname, fullname_timestamp, age, age_timestamp)
```

and I'd like to update only those columns whose '*_timestamp' column is less than the given value. for example:

```
UPDATE contact
SET    fullname = 'john doe' IF fullname_timestamp < 12345,
       age = 30 IF age_timestamp < 12345
WHERE  contactid = 'abcde'
```

putting these conditions in the WHERE clause would make an "all-or-nothing" scenario (I think?), whereas I'd like to "partially update" a record given these "timestamp" constraints.

Is this possible / am I doing it wrong? Suggestions welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Edit: @AaronBertrand raised a few good points and I think they're worth mentioning as additional info to the question. I'll also admit I'm still putting together a solution in my head, and there might be gaps in my thinking.

I'm replicating data contained in an external product. This product has a well defined pipeline of CRUD events. Due to performance reasons, I'm managing these event asynchronously. 
These events might be queued out-of-order for later processing. 
I'm using DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks timestamps in one of the non-async pipeline stages of the aforementioned product - so that records are correctly timestamped - and I have means to tell if the data I'm about to update is up-to-date or stale.

```
-- sync pipeline --

record update 1 - timestamp 1
record update 2 - timestamp 2

-- async queue (can be out-of-order) --
record update 2 - timestamp 2 -> sent to db
record update 1 - timestamp 1 -> sent to db

-- replica db  --
record update 2 goes through, the timestamp is ok
record update 1 does nothing, timestamp shows data is out-of-date
```

And yes, updates can happen to the same records concurrently. Users could be modifying the same or different fields at the same time.
Hope this makes sense. Thanks everyone for the great input.

Comment: . . Do you also want to change the timestamp if you change the value?

Comment: that's actually a good question, @GordonLinoff. Yes I do. I think timestamps have a specific meaning in SQL, right now I'm thinking of DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.

Comment: . . you should investigate key/value pairs as Robertco suggests.  It might be a better structure for your data.

Comment: Do you think it is beneficial to only partly update a row? ([In my tests, just updating the whole row always won, performance-wise](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/conditional-updates).) Are you relying on the timestamp to validate whether the value has actually changed? Why not compare values? This smells an awful lot like premature optimization. If you're going to update *any* value in the row, you may as well update the whole row. I don't think your structure is ideal for maintaining a history of sorts for each column value. What will you do with this information anyway?

Comment: Also if you're using `DateTime.UtcNow` as a comparison, won't all values in the table already be less than that at the time of an update, by definition?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I'll add more info to the question.

Comment: If you're deferring a bunch of updates until later, why don't you merge the rows (taking the latest value for each column), and just update each row once? You seem to be performing this logic in the wrong place. IMHO.

Comment: @AaronBertrand it's an interesting option; basically buffer updates in a key-value store, and pick the latest values - then clearing the store? I might be doing this in the same transaction for atomicity. I wonder what would drive the actual record update after N millisecs of buffering (or another criteria)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CASE` on this to test for specific condition of a certain column,

```
UPDATE contact
SET    fullname = CASE WHEN fullname_timestamp < 12345 THEN 'john doe' ELSE fullname END,
       age = CASE WHEN age_timestamp < 12345 THEN 30 ELSE age END
WHERE  contactid = 'abcde'
```

Comment: excellent! I think this is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you. (9 mins to go...)

Comment: Correct answer, but you might want to consider key/value pair, if you plan to timestamp every column.

Comment: @RobertCo can you expand on that? I'd love to learn different practices.

Comment: Obviously, I shouldn't pretend to know what you are trying to do. But I will anyway. If you want to create a "log" of changes, you can do better than timestamp on very columnn. Remove the timestamp on your main table and create a separate table with the ff columns: contact_id, attr_id, timestamp, where attr id is an id assigned to every column you plan to monitor, then just keep inserting to it.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, and I will surely consider this should I need logging facilities. in this particular case, however, my goal is to prevent updates coming from an out-of-order source.

Comment: @Raine does "out-of-order" mean two concurrent updates co-mingling? Otherwise can you expand on what you're trying to prevent?